# would be nothing vs wouldn’t be anything

Tags: modal-verbs

I wonder if you could explain me why the second version isn't used, only the first one.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wouldn%E2%80%99t%20be%20anything%20interesting%2Cwould%20be%20nothing%20interesting&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&case_insensitive=on&corpus=15&smoothing=50&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20be%20nothing%20interesting%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwould%20be%20nothing%20interesting%3B%2Cc0)

As I understand, there is no grammatical mistake in the second sentence, isn't it?

> I’m sure there **would be nothing** interesting there.
>
> I’m sure there **wouldn’t be anything** interesting there.

Comment: I think this might be a quirk of Ngrams or a bug.  If you do a Google Books search for **wouldn't be anything interesting**, there are plenty of results: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wouldn%27t+be+anything+interesting%22

Comment: *There **is nothing** wrong with this sentence.* Equally, *there **isn't anything** wrong with this one* - it's just a more verbose (and hence, less *likely*) way of saying exactly the same thing. The "grammatical mistake" that needs correcting here is *As I understand **it*** (or ***things***), *there is no grammatical mistake in the second sentence, **is there**?*